# ¿Por qué tengo un error con la ruta de las vistas en handlebars?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, views, handlebars.js

```
const path = require('path')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')

const morgan = require('morgan');
const multer = require('multer');
const express = require('express');
const erroHandler = require('errorhandler')
const routes = require('../routes/index');

module.exports = app => {

    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 80)
    console.log(__dirname) 
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
    app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    extName: '.hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials' ),
    layoutDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    helpers: require('../helpers')
}))
    app.set('view engine', '.hbs');


    // middlewares
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(multer({dest: path.join(__dirname, '../public/upload/temp')}).single('image'))
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    app.use(express.json());

    //routes
    routes(app)

    // static files
    app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));


    // errorhandlers
    if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
        app.use(erroHandler)
    }

    return app;
}
```

Me retorna este error y la verdad no tengo idea de por qué

> Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory
>   "C:\Users\Diesan Romero\Desktop\redsocial\views"

estos son mis directorios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo cual supongo y no debería de dar ese error.

Comment: Esta claro que no lo encuentra en el directorio `...\redsocial\views"` donde debería apuntar en `\redsocial\src\views"`... baja un nivel de directorio, ósea quita el `../` delante

Comment: @aldanux esto es lo que pasa cuando hago eso: Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "C:\Users\Diesan Romero\Desktop\redsocial\src\server\views" es por eso que subí un nivel de directorio